# How to fetch data from express backend using React

Tags: reactjs, express

Im having trouble accessing data from my backend using express, I am also sort of confused on how i should set up my routing. Do I only need express routes for when I have to dig something out of my database?

My User component

```js
import React from 'react';

class User extends React.Component {
    state = {
        username: ""
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch("/api/:user")
            .then(res =>res.json()
            .then(data => {
                console.log("data", JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
                this.setState({data}) 
            }))
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.username}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default User;
```

my user routes, the route is /api/:user

```js
router.get("/:user", (req, res)=>{
    // find user
    console.log(req.params);
    User.find({username:req.params.user}, (err, foundUser)=>{
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.json(foundUser);
        }
    });
});
```

when i console.log(req.params) it returns :user, not the actual user requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am giving a sample code for you to learn.

In the App.js we define the routes using [react-router-dom](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start) package.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Redirect,
  Switch,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";
import Users from "./Users";
import User from "./User";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Link to="/">Users</Link>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Users} />
        <Route path="/:userId/" exact component={User} />
        <Redirect to="/" />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

In Users component, we get a list of users from jsonplaceholder api and list them, give a dynamic link with a userId to the User component.

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

class Users extends React.Component {
  state = {
    users: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(users => this.setState({ users }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.state.users.map(user => (
          <li key={user.id}>
            <Link to={`/${user.id}`}> {user.name}</Link>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

export default Users;
```

In the user component, we get the userId param from `this.props.match.params.userId`,
and using that userId we call another api to get user details.

```
import React from "react";

class User extends React.Component {
  state = {
    user: null
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${this.props.match.params.userId}`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(user => {
        this.setState({ user });
      });
  }

  render() {
    const { user } = this.state;

    if (!user) return <div>Loading user...</div>;

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>User Name: {user.name}</h1>
        <p>Email: {user.email}</p>
        <p>Website: {user.website}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default User;
```

Note that we dynamically constructed the user detail api url by with [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) using the backtick character. This was one of the problems you had in your code.

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-hypatia-5pehl)

Comment: Thank you so much, if i had the rep to upvote i would!

Comment: @noahdubs you can mark as answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

In your url, the `:user` is a way to say in the backend code "a value goes at this place", and this must be the user id from the database I presume.

So in the React code you should do :

```
const userId = 4 // the id of the user that you want to fetch
fetch(`/api/${userId}`)
```

Comment: How do I get that userId with react? is there a way to access the request?

Comment: It's up to you to decide which user you fetch, since the endpoint seems to give you any user you want, you're just saying "I want this one". You can see the request in your browser in the dev tools : on Chrome hit Ctrl + Shift + I -> Network tab -> XHR, it will appear here.